# HTML fixed word distance?

Tags: html

I am a HTML noob that has to set up a little web-application.

What I want to display on my page are essentially 2 lines such as:

```
The car drove
DT  NN  V
```

Both lines have the same number of words. I want to align the words of the second line to their corresponding word in the first line - pretty much like the auto-markup of stack overflow presents it right now. How can I achieve that in HTML?

Comment: Why don't you use a `table`? **[Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)**

Comment: The title of the question does not correspond to the content of the question at all. To align words, they need to have *different* distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; border:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
```

```html
<table class="tg" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">The</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">car</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">drove</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">DT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">NN</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">V</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>The</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>drove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DT</td>
    <td>NN</td>
    <td>V</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```